# I cannot use firejail keepasssc with Bionic Beaver

Tags: gtk, sandbox, ubuntu-18.04

KeepassXC just hangs there with 18.04 installed. I have to use Ctrl-c on the firejail terminal window to close it. I had no such problem with 16.04 installed. By the way, there is an error relating to GTK appearing with 18.04 which did not appear with 16.04 -> "Theme parsing error: gtk-lubuntu.css".

Comment: I might consider using Flatpak instead of Firejail, but no browser can run within Flatpak -> https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/linux-application-sandboxing-and.html

Comment: Sorry; I just noticed that keepasssc appears in the title instead of keepassxc and there is no way that I know of to edit the title...

Answer (score 0):

KeepassXC 2.3.4 and the GitHub version of Firejail solved my problem. Thanks to the developers of both projects, which together help make the Web a safer place for all.